# Magento Setting up EcomDev error : Cannot find local.xml.phpunit file in app/etc directory

Tags: magento-1.9, ecomdev-phpunit

I have a `Magento` project and I am trying to implement unit testing in it.

For this I am using `EcomDev`.

I am following this [Tutorial](https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_PHPUnit) and did the prerequisites:

> 1. install composer;
> 2. create a composer.json file for installing PHPUnit and EcomDev module;
> 3. setup PHPUnit by creating the phpunit.xml configuration file;
> 4. create the bootstrap file for PHPUnit;

So, since I used composer for installing `EcomDev` (not modman).

And in the `EcomDev` official [github repo](https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_PHPUnit), we have to run the following commands as mentioned:

```
php ecomdev-phpunit.php -a magento-config --db-name magento_test --base-url http://local.fresh.com/
```

And I get the following error:

> Cannot find local.xml.phpunit file in app/etc directory⏎

What should I be doing in this case, as I can't find any information about adding `local.xml.phpunit` manually.

PS : I am using `Magento 1.9`

Answer (score 0):

Running the following line before running the said line does the job for me:

> php -f ecomdev-phpunit.php -- --action install